# Can't type anything into Terminal

Tags: terminal

I was in the process of installing Zend Server on my iMac OSX 10.8.2. I was near the end when it wasnt working properly, so I started over by typing in the first command:

```
sudo nano /usr/local/zend/bin/zendctl.sh
```

Then this was returned and I can't type anything into Terminal. I've closed the window and reopened, still the same. The folks on the Apple Discussion forums suggested I delete the /usr/local/zend folder and restart Terminal, which I did, but still have the same issue. Nobody there seems to have experienced this so they directed me here.

Here's what is now in my Terminal window:

```
http://forums.zend.com/download/file.php?id=3028
```

This is what it looks like when I open a new window.

I logged in with another account on my machine and the same thing happens. I'm stumped. The Apple helpers are stumped. I'm hoping someone here can unstump this whole mess.

Comment: You, sir, rock! I repaired permissions and all is well.

Answer (score 2):

This error is apparently the non-obvious result of [incorrect permissions](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1197937). Use the [Repair Disk Permissions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1452) feature of Disk Utility to fix it.